# how to get process id of specific process?

Tags: linux, bash, process, grep, ps

Say there are 3 process with names `abc`, `abcd` and `abcde`.

I'm using the following command to find out the process id:

```
ps -ef | grep abc | grep -v grep
```

This gives the output for all the 3 processes with their corresponding pids:

```
user 6009      1   0   May 11 ?           0:23 ./abc
user 28047     1   0   Apr 24 ?           0:04 ./abcd
user 28548     1   0   Apr 27 ?           0:04 ./abcde
```

Now what I want is a grep thing that outputs the process id of just `abc` without returning `abcd` and `abcde`. I know using `grep -v "processname"` eliminates what i want but is there anything simple and specific?

Comment: If there is any answer here, that suits your needs, it would be nice of you to accept that one, by clicking the green hook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ps -ef | grep -w abc | grep -v grep
               ^
               `--- match whole words only
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)

Comment: @KuntalShaw, don't forget to accept an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

sure, there is:

```
pidof
```

Here is the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof

For example write:

```
pidof abc
```

output:

```
6009
```

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) is for.

Specifically, for this you would use `pgrep -x abc`.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having to pipe into `grep -v grep`, do this:

```
ps -ef | grep '[a]bc\>'
```

the `\>` is an end-of-word boundary marker, so you won't match "abcd" or "abcde"

Putting one character into a bracket expression means that regex will match the string `abc` but it will not match the string `grep [a]bc`

I do this often enough that I wrote a function, `psg`

```
psg () { 
    local -a patterns=()
    (( $# == 0 )) && set -- $USER
    for arg do
        patterns+=( "-e" "[${arg:0:1}]${arg:1}" )
    done
    ps -ef | grep "${patterns[@]}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -ef | grep -w 'abc$' | grep -v grep
```

i.e. end of line (`$`) after `abc`

Comment: It is working with my `ps` - I would not know of different standards regarding this program. But probably the `-w` option as suggested by @eugeniu-rosca is the save way.